# What were the findings of the Acts Seminar?

Tags: exegesis, acts

The [Seminar on Acts of the Apostles](https://www.westarinstitute.org/projects/the-jesus-seminar/seminar-on-the-acts-of-the-apostles/) sat for ten years until 2011, examining the Acts of the Apostles. What were its main findings and how were they arrived at?

Comment: [Is this on topic?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6065/30)

Comment: **Mod notice:** _‹some comments removed›_ Please keep discussion about the topicality of this post on the [relevant meta post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6065/30). Splitting the discussion between there and comments isn't helping.

Answer (score -2):

The Acts Seminar was one of several seminars set up by [The Westar Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westar_Institute) as "large-scale, collaborative research projects" on various topics in early Christian history. Fellows attending and voting at the [Seminars](http://www.westarinstitute.org/projects/) are academics in theology, Bible studies and cognate fields.  The voting system was based on traditional scholarly practice, whereby each member of the Seminar assigned a colour to his or her response to a question after full discussion, as described by the institute's Wikipedia page:

> - RED: This information is virtually certain; it is supported by a preponderance of the evidence and is accepted as historical.
> - PINK: This information is not certain but is probably reliable; it fits well with evidence that is verifiable and so is regarded as
>     borderline historical.
> - GRAY: This information is possible but unreliable; it is not a clear fabrication but lacks supporting evidence and so is regarded as
>     dubious.
> - BLACK: This information is improbable; it does not fit verifiable evidence or seems to be a fabrication and is regarded as
>     nonhistorical.

As described by the [Seminar summary report](https://www.westarinstitute.org/projects/the-jesus-seminar/seminar-on-the-acts-of-the-apostles/), the goal was to go through the canonical Acts of the Apostles from beginning to end and evaluate it for historical accuracy.  The Seminar announced that its principal findings were:

> 1. The use of *Acts* as a source for history has long needed critical
>      reassessment.
> 2. *Acts* was written in the early decades of the second century.
> 3. The author of *Acts* used the letters of Paul as sources.
> 4. Except for the letters of Paul, no other historically reliable
>      source can be identified for *Acts*.
> 5. *Acts* can no longer be considered an independent source for the life
>      and mission of Paul.
> 6. Contrary to Acts 1-7, Jerusalem was not the birthplace of
>      Christianity.
> 7. *Acts* constructs its story on the model of epic and related
>      literature.
> 8. The author of *Acts* created names for characters as storytelling
>      devices.
> 9. *Acts* constructs its story to fit ideological goals.
> 10. *Acts* is a primary historical source for second century
>        Christianity.

"The Seminar has not found a core historical story of Christian beginnings in *Acts*", which is "not to say that *Acts* is totally unhistorical but to observe that it is less helpful in the historical reconstruction of Christian beginnings than previously assumed."

The full report of the Seminar is published as  *[Acts and Christian Beginnings: The Acts Seminar Report](http://www.westarinstitute.org/store/acts-and-christian-beginnings/)* (Polebridge Press, 2013), edited by Dennis E. Smith, Joseph B. Tyson.

Comment: Did they address whether the author claimed to be a companion of Paul or not? (The "we" passages are often cited as evidence, but I've seen arguments that they don't actually mean that.) Do they regard it as the work of a single author/redactor? If so, is it the same person as the Gospel of Luke? Regarding 6, what did they say *was* the birthplace of Christianity?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I will be ordering a copy of the final report and when I have received and read this I will be able to answer these questions.  Sorry I can't do so just yet.

Comment: 50% of this post is copy and paste from the seminar's site with no indication that it isn't your own material. That's not okay — and this is something we've pointed out before on your posts. Copy & pasting any content  and posting it with your name  under it and no credits or formatting  to indicate a citation is plagiarism. Don't do that.

Comment: Another question, regarding number 3: which of the Pauline epistles are considered to have been used as sources? Did it include the Pastorals? What about Hebrews?

Comment: Hi @Mr.Bultitude That's an interesting question, too much to answer in a short comment. If you could ask it as a question in its own right, I'll try to do it justice.  Please state whether you want the view of the Acts Seminar or of scholars more broadly.